# How to let width of a table depend on the td's width?

Tags: html, html-table, width

I have a table which has a inner table. I don't want to set the `table`'s width, but the `td`'s width:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td width="200">left menus (200px)</td>
        <td>
            <table border="1" class="table-fixed" style="background-color:#ddd" >
                <tr>
                    <td width="2000">2000px</td>
                    <td width="2000">2000px</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can see the inner table has two `td`s, the total width is `4000`, which is wider than the browser.

But in the browser, the table is automatically shrank to fit the browser. How to let the table displays by it's actual width ( 200+2000+2000 here ).

If I set the table's width as:

```
<table width="4200">
    ...
            <table width="4000">
    ...
</table>
```

It will be displayed as I expected, but I don't want to. Since the columns of inner table are dynamic, I don't get the total width before running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS min-width to force that.

http://jsfiddle.net/kM6DQ/

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td width="200">left menus (200px)</td>
        <td>
            <table border="1" class="table-fixed" style="background-color:#ddd" >
                <tr>
                    <td class="wide">2000px</td>
                    <td class="wide">2000px</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<style>
td.wide { width:2000px; min-width:2000px; }

</style>
```